# Row-Column agnostic Matrix datastructure

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, space-complexity

Due to the linear nature of computer memory, row-major and column-major matrices have different performance for row- vs. column access. The obvious solution would be to keep two copies of the same data sorted accordingly. Is there a DS with better space complexity?

Comment: You can have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliffe_vector

Comment: Thanks. An Iliffe vector is just a vector of pointers to arrays, so doesn't  unify column vs. row access. For matrices with big data nodes a linked 'grid' (vs. linked list) might be an option.